# Subtract between matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a loop to do the following:

Two matrices, A and B, I want to subtract the first element in A from each element of B individually and then move on to the next element of A, and then save the results in a new matrix C.

Example with A and B = 2x2 matrices:

```
a1 = np.subtract(b[0, 0], a[0, 0]) #difference between all elements in b and first element in a
a2 = np.subtract(b[0, 1], a[0, 0])

a3 = np.subtract(b[1, 0], a[0, 0])
a4 = np.subtract(b[1, 0], a[0, 0])

b1 = np.subtract(b[0, 0], a[0, 1]) #difference between all elements in b and second element in a
b2 = np.subtract(b[0, 1], a[0, 1])

b3 = np.subtract(b[1, 0], a[0, 1])
b4 = np.subtract(b[1, 1], a[0, 1])

c1 = np.subtract(b[0, 0], a[1, 0]) #difference between all elements in b and third element in a
c2 = np.subtract(b[0, 1], a[1, 0])

c3 = np.subtract(b[1, 0], a[1, 0])
c4 = np.subtract(b[1, 1], a[1, 0])

d1 = np.subtract(b[0, 0], a[1, 1]) #difference between all elements in b and fourth element in a
d2 = np.subtract(b[0, 1], a[1, 1])

d3 = np.subtract(b[1, 0], a[1, 1])
d4 = np.subtract(b[1, 1], a[1, 1])

q = np.array([[a1, a2, a3, a4], [b1, b2, b3, b4], [c1, c2, c3, c4], [d1, d2, d3, d4]])
q
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do... Sounds that you need to loop over all indices and manually define what you want to do.

Comment: so you end up with a 4D matrix?

Comment: Yeah, its hard to explain hehe. I want to see the difference between each individual element in both matrices

Comment: make an example with two 2x2 matrices and the desired output. For what you say your new matrix C needs to have 4 dimensions.

Comment: I submitted a change now where I have two 2x2 without any loop

Comment: `a.reshape(-1) - b.reshape(-1,1)` IIUC. I think *a4* has an error in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I indexed a1-4 as when I subtracted all elements in b with a[0, 0], and b1-4 when I subtracted all elements in b with a[0, 1]. It was just to visualize what I want to do in my loop. The output I get here is the desired output, but I want to to create a for loop which does this for a much larger matrix.

Comment: You have a bug in your example code `a4 = np.subtract(b[1, 0], a[0, 0])` should be `a4 = np.subtract(b[1, 1], a[0, 0])`. You don't need a loop with `numpy`, a solution is in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped a lot. If I want to expand this to a much larger matrix, I just swap out the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This is a for loop to do this:

```
for ele in np.nditer(a):
   a_sub = np.tile(np.array([ele]),(b.shape[0], b.shape[1]))
   b -= a_sub
```